# math expression of user input in Scientific Calculator

Tags: android

I want to make android scientific calculator showing user input as mathematical expression like textbook format.e.g, When a button for a fraction is clicked, a box of numerator and denominator appear for user input.Plz give me a hand.

Comment: Are you running into any specific errors that I should know about?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app#0

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can give you ahead start
i have created an xml for dialog that has the boxes where you enter the fraction's nominators and denominators, her below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/fractionLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nominator"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_white"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/denominator"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_white"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fractionLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Ok" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then also a xml that has a button for the fraction, and inside this xml i have created an onClick = "fraction", a method that is implemented inside the main activity, to handle the button click, but you can do this in anyway you feel comfortable with.

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fraction"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fraction"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:onClick="fraction" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And to make th EditTexts look a bit cute that isjust for me you can also do it the way you want i made an drawble xml that i set it as the Edittexts backgrounds, here it is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" /> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
</shape>
```

Now for the Activity part to handle the fuctionality heres the code, note that is is well commented you can easily understand it

```
import android.app.Dialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    //onclick fucntion created from the XML
    fun fraction(view: View) {
        //create a dialog to call the fraction input boxes
        val fraction = Dialog(this)
        fraction.setContentView(R.layout.trial)


        // find the fraction boxes
        val nominator = fraction.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nominator)
        val denominator = fraction.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.denominator)
        val okBtn = fraction.findViewById<Button>(R.id.ok)

        //get the text entered from the fraction boxes
        val nom = nominator.text
        val den = denominator.text

        okBtn.setOnClickListener {
            //dismiss the fraction dialog
            fraction.dismiss()

            //show th values entered in the boxes
            Toast.makeText(this, "${nom}/${den}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        fraction.show()
    }
}
```

This should give you an idea on way to go with your app. Thanks